# How to get the AjaxRequestTarget inside Wicket's onBeforeRender() method of a component?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

I have an Ajax event that triggers the redraw of various Wicket panels. Some panels have additional calculations of their own inside their onBeforeRender() method. If there is an error, I want to display it to the user. But I can't add the FeedbackPanel to the AjaxRequestTarget because I don't have access to it anymore inside the panel that is being redrawn.

Is there a way to get the AjaxRequestTarget inside onBeforeRender() of a Wicket component? Is it even possible to add additional components to the Ajax target once the first ones are already in onBeforeRender() state?

Is there a better way to add the FeedbackPanel to the Ajax target if only the panels that need to be redrawn can decide if there is an error or not?

Comment: I dont know what your app is doing but i doubt that business logic calculation on `onBeforeRender()` is a good idea.

Comment: There was a static [`AjaxRequestTarget.get()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#get()) method back in Wicket 1.4 (seems to be gone in Wicket 6). However, as Robert already pointed out, validation logic and morevoer error reporting shouldn't be handled in `onBeforeRender()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting the `AjaxTarget` is done like this:

```
AjaxRequestTarget target = requestCycle.find(AjaxRequestTarget.class);
```

Unfortunately, like expected, I can't add components to the target once I'm in the rendering phase. But Wicket provides the interface [`ITargetRespondListener`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.ITargetRespondListener.html) with the method `onTargetRespond(AjaxRequestTarget target)`. Here I can add anything I want to the target.

Comment: For future readers. When even less context is available: `RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)`

Comment: How to get it in Wicket version 8? It is not the same way cause when I update the dependencies to version 8 it says something is wrong, but in documentation the definition of find method is the same