# Wicket open Bookmarkable page on new tab

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `WebPage` in Wicket with `PageParameters` so that it could be used via `BookMarkablePageLink`.

I can open it also giving:

```
 setResponsePage(MyPage.class, params);
```

, but what I cannot do is open it similar way as a new tab.

I use a form and there in `onSubmit()` -method I want to call the page and place it to tab. I cannot figure out how I could

> a) validate form
>     b) open the page on successful validation
>     c) page appearing in a new tab.

How to make the part `c`? I know how to validate and open page, please help me about the opening to a tab.

For the form I give `target="_blank"`, but did not help, maybe due the fact of using the `setResponsePage()` method.

**EDIT:**

This is not a duplicate of [Open new Tab when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121236/wicket-how-to-open-new-tab-when-button-is-clickd) because none of solutions worked.

Page is opened in `AjaxSubmitLink`'s `onSubmit()` method with `setReponsePage()`. I have to validate form before sending, thus direct Bookmarkable link or form is not a case. Adding to tag `target="_blank"` works if you directly open after click. I have to validate first and then I try to set the response page like stated above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wicket ,how to open new tab when button is clickd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121236/wicket-how-to-open-new-tab-when-button-is-clickd)

Comment: @thg: Actually, not. Look my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution from a list in other Q&A. [[1]](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Open-new-Tab-via-form-target-td3624578.html)

It states:

> dont use an ajax button, they do not respect the target attribute.

I will try to submit the form with ajaxlink. My validations work with ajax, but I can use

```
RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class)
```

to get the needed `AjaxTarget`. [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246892/how-to-get-the-ajaxrequesttarget-inside-wickets-onbeforerender-method-of-a-co)

Sources:

[1] http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Open-new-Tab-via-form-target-td3624578.html

[2] [How to get the AjaxRequestTarget inside Wicket's onBeforeRender() method of a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246892/how-to-get-the-ajaxrequesttarget-inside-wickets-onbeforerender-method-of-a-co)

Comment: My fellow worker fixed the issue for me before I found the answer. He stayed with ajaxForm, but opened link with a `target.appendJavaScript("window.open('"+ url +"');return false;");` call. Same solution almost, just not to relying on `ajaxLink`'s functionality.

Answer (score 3):

This 'onclick' html attribute works for me (at least in IE, Firefox and Chrome):

`<input onclick="target='_blank';return true;" type="submit" value="text on button"/>`

Okay, i don't know how this exactly works but i find it much smarter than doing some complex stuff in your java code.